# Protractor: Logging into app with API call

Tags: protractor

I am trying to move away from Cypress.io back to Protractor, (Cypress doesn't have cross-browser functionality we need). One of the nice things about Cypress is the ability to make an API call to log in to the application.

I am wondering how to do this with protractor.

This is my login request:

```
async apiLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    const PostURL = browser.baseUrl + 'api/auth/login'
    console.log(`Logging in as ${email}`)
    const body = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
    }
    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
    this.request
        .post(PostURL)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .send(body)
        // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
        .end(function(err: string, response: any) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Login post error = ${err}`)
            } else {
                console.log(`Login post response = ${response.status}`)
            }
        })
}
```

The problem that I am running into on protractor is that I get a successful request, but then it just sits on the login page.

This is my `beforeAll()` method where I log in and then try to navigate to the area of the application I am looking to get to.

```
        beforeAll(async () => {
            await loginPage.apiLogin(user.email, user.password)
            await browser.get(browser.baseUrl + 'explorations/new')
    })
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the API call, I switched over to Axios

```
   async loginAPI(email: string, password: string) {
    const PostURL = browser.baseUrl + 'api/auth/login'
    const requestBody = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
    }
    const response = await axios.post(PostURL, requestBody, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })

    const csrfToken = await response.headers['set-cookie'][0].split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
    const sessionID = await response.headers['set-cookie'][1].split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
    const results = {
        csrfToken,
        sessionID,
    }
    return results
}
```

Then using it:

```
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const sessionInfo = await loginPage.loginAPI(user.email, user.password)
        const csrftoken = await sessionInfo.csrfToken
        const sessionID = await sessionInfo.sessionID
        await browser.manage().addCookie({
            name: 'csrftoken',
            value: csrftoken,
        })
        await browser.manage().addCookie({
            name: 'sessionid',
            value: sessionID,
        })
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl + 'home')
    })
```